Crop the title (text) on the image to a certain border (by color)
How can I cut out a title from an image along the border of the lower red background (examples below)? I am planning a batch process, i.e. with hundreds of images with different titles (both with different widths and heights - only their location is constant). I'm using bash.

Example 1:



Example 2:



Desired Output:



Make everything that is not red become black. Find the trim box.

Is the "Just Text" section always in red?  You said it was always in the same place?  Is that really correct? What did you mean by that?  Is the size and placement of the red box always the same? Please clarify. If the top of the red box is always in the same location, then you can just crop off the white text above it.

@fmw42, The red section is always the same size and text. I need to remove everything before it, leaving a small ridge on top with a black background.

What is your platform and Imagemagick version?

You have not said what you platform is nor what version of Imagemagick you are using. So I will assume Imagemagick 6 on a Unix-like system (Linux, Mac OSX or Windows 10/11 unix).
This is the approach suggested by Mark Setchell in his comment above. (Make everything that is not red into black. Then trim to the red box bounds and find the top of the red box. Then chop off the top of the image down to the red box. Then add some black padding to the top of the image.)
Here is the manual way in case you are on Windows. Sorry, I do not know how to deal with variables.
Get the top of the red box, shave it off, then splice back a 20 pixel high black region on the top as pad.
convert image1.png -fuzz 1% -fill black +opaque "rgb(237,28,36)" -format "%@" info:

That returns the WxH+X+Y and we just want Y
364x28+256+182
Then chop of the top 182 and splice back 20 pixel tall blacktop the top of the image.
convert image1.png +repage -gravity north -chop 0x182 -background black -splice 0x20 new_image1.png

Here is the more automated way in Unix syntax.
top=$(convert image1.png +repage -fuzz 1% -fill black +opaque "rgb(237,28,36)" -format "%@" info: | tr "x" "+" | cut -d+ -f4)
convert image1.png -gravity north -chop 0x$top -background black -splice 0x20 new_image1.png

Here is the result of either sets of commands above:

If on Imagemagick 7, just change convert to magick.

Yeah, great answer. Now at least I have an idea of the tool.

But it cuts to the text outline. Can I do it to trim along the edge of the red section? Just reduce Y?

What do you mean by "just reduce Y"? Your desired image showed that you wanted a gap at the top. Why is the white arrow there if you did not want that?  If you do not want that gap, remove -background black -splice 0x20. Or decrease 20. It would be better if your desired example showed exactly what you really wanted for the output or you explained it better.

I meant that it cuts off the red border to the outline of the text, but should leave space on top (red) as in the original. The top black border is also needed. In general, I did it, I just subtracted 10 from Y.

I posted my result.  It seems fine, if I understand what you want.  Please clarify what is wrong with that output. I also added +repage to the commands in case the PNG inputs have a virtual canvas offset.

If you have an input PNG that does not work as above in my example, post that image and I will look at it and see why that might be.
